The upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04 completely ruined my Dell Optiplex 3010. What do I do?
My main question is: is there a step-by-step guide to restore Ubuntu 22.04 or to fix 24.04?
Second question: is there a way to start a command prompt (with this broken system)?
About 70% of my applications appear to be gone. There is one screen with a few App icons. Essential system features are not accessible like commands, terminals, or a way to view folders. I cannot enter commands like ls, cd, sudo apt install, and so on. Some random applications are visible and work when I hit the 'Windows' key like Zoom and Firefox. Some like Bitwarden are visible and do not work. Some of the features are new with 24.04 but they are not working either. For example, there is a new/alternate way to enter commands but no commands work.
I cannot access folders and cannot start any terminal. At one point I was able to get to a command prompt but I have not been able to repeat that - I think it requires a reboot.
This old computer was great with 22.04.

You can open a virtual terminal (described in the linked answer), and enter the commands in the linked answer to fix the issue.

If that does not work, then reinstall Ubuntu 24.04 from a live media

I executed these recommendations. Control/Alt/F3 does work.

Do the commands in the other answer fix the issue (you will have to reboot)

I think this is almost impossible to write a common reusable answer to. There are probably more things wrong after a broken upgrade. Trying to write an answer here would at best be a guess - at worst lead you down a wrong path that could do more damage. I suggest - if you have another pc - to go to IRC / Libera.Chat and try interactive help via the #ubuntu channel.

I am installing the 64-bit Ubuntu 22.04 from the live install USB I used 8 or so months ago. I chose to overwrite 24.04.  From studying the web and trying the other suggestions, a fresh install seems best.   I do not trust 24.04 now. I suspect I will have to reinstall many programs.
